# How do you recognize a spot container instance on Azure?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I've been making a proof of concept with the new Spot Containers from Microsoft on Azure's Container Instances offering. That all works fine as expected. But... I just can't visually verify anywhere that it's actually a spot container. Not in the portal, not in any of its properties I can retrieve via Azure CLI or anything. Does anyone have an idea or can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to recognize a spot container instance on the Azure portal and I was able to retrieve that successfully.

Spot container instances on Azure cannot be viewed directly, while creating the container instance, choose ‘`run with azure spot discount`’ to select it as **Spot container instances**. Since Spot container instances are subject to termination at any time. The second option is to go to your container instance and click on properties you should find the word ‘`azure spot`’ mentioned. Also, another way is, if your container instance has a termination policy of “`Preemptible`”, it is likely a spot instance.

```
az container list --filter "termination policy eq 'Preemptible'"
```

This info can also be achieved while creating the container instance which is to be created with `Azure spot discount` enabled while creating so.

[image]

Once the creation of the container instance was done then navigate through the path mentioned.

**Container instance --> Properties -->Azure Spot (Yes)**

[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-deploy-spot-containers-portal

Comment: thanks for replying. I am aware of that documentation. That's the thing. I have chosen "Run with Azure Spot discount," and I can see it occasionally killing and starting the container. But it says at the properties: "Azure Spot - ". Also, the Restart Policy = On Failure.  But I'll flag your answer because it should be correct. I'm just not seeing it right now in practice.